# Are objects used for the Taanugim "muktzeh" for Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur, yom-tov, muktzeh, inuy-affliction

The five prohibitions of inuy on Yom Kippur are eating/drinking, bathing, anointing, sex, and wearing leather shoes. Would an object whose only use is for these prohibited pleasures be considered "muktzeh" for Yom Kippur (or subject to an equivalent prohibition against moving them)? Might food/drink being prepared in a permissible way for the break fast constitute an exception to such a rule, if it exists?* Assume the object in question is not muktzeh for Shabbos.

*I'm not sure that there *is* a permissible way to do this during Yom Kippur proper, but I have seen the balebustes of very frum families doing so.

Comment: Anything used for eating is fine at least, because you can give food to children

Comment: I remember a similar discussion with you before several month, and if I remember right there is a minhag to crack nuts, following this minhag, may be an answer for all food. not absolutely sure.

Comment: @SAH are you sure that the tag "yom-tow" is necessary?

Comment: I don't think food is muktzeh on YK, per @Heshy's comment. However, the way you have phrased the question appears like  *hachanah* (preparation on "Shabbat" - Yom Kippur is like Shabbat) for afterwards which is certainly prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

The Ramma at the end of siman 612 brings fro the Trumas Hadeshen that there is no issue of muktza for food or drink.

> מותר ליגע ביום כיפור באוכלין ומשקין וליתן לקטנים ולא חיישינן שיאכל או ישתה עם יגע

Magen Avraham as brought in Mishna Berurah and Aruch HaShulchan points out that is different than Pesach as brought in shulchan aruch 446:3. There, since a person is eating other food we are afraid he will forget himself and eat the assur food he is touching. On Yom kippur this does not apply. Also  on Y.K. the fearfullness of the day is upon him.

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav verbalizes the M.A. differently. He writes in siman 611 that touching food is always allowed. Preparing food, which is naturally more involving is only allowed when preparing it for someone who needs it like a child or a sick person. The only difference would be preparing food for no express purpose which seems trivial and impractical and we might assume the M.B. and A.H. agree. (preparing food for after Yom Kippur is mentioned below)

They all say that if the child can feed himself there is still no reason for the adult to be stringent.

Since touching food leads into discussions of hachana, which is actually the point of siman 611, see there for the discussion. Nowadays we have no leniency and we do not allow preparing food for after Yom Kippur even though this was allowed in talmudic times later in the day.

I didn't see anyone discussing the other items related to the affliction of the day, such as leather shoes. But let's remember that of all the five items, only eating and drinking would have a punishment of kareis. It would be logical to be stricter with those.

Comment: What about preparing food on Yom Kippur for a diabetic or elderly who must eat by a specific time that is at the exact moment that YK ends?

Comment: I'm assuming kal vichomer to be muttar. Or at least hu hadin of his hetter to eat and be prepared for on yom tov. But I like that question. It might be a stronger question on a regular shabbos or on y.k with a food that needs prep from before mincha. Bec on Y.k. at least midina digemara we have a hetter for preparing from after mincha.