# Can seforim be muktze on tish'a b'av that falls on shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, torah-study, tisha-bav, muktzeh

If tish'a b'av were to fall on shabbos, would the sections of Torah prohibited for study on tish'a b'av cause the seforim in which they are found to be muktze?  If in a given sefer there are prohibited sections together with permitted sections of study (e.g. a nach) then I assume the permitted material would not make the entire sefer muktze since one can read it on tish'a b'av.   Also, if such seforim are muktze, which category or categories of muktze would they be and why?

Comment: Not everyone prohibits any Torah study on that Shabbat

Comment: How is this different from books that can't be read in any other Shabbat (eg. business books probably).?

Comment: reading or consulting a book is permitted,

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76862/are-objects-used-for-the-taanugim-muktzeh-for-yom-kippur

Answer (score 2):

When shabos came in it was not muktze because it was permitted to use it. Then it can't become muktze unless it changed to a different shape.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Yosel! Adding in sources would greatly improve this post.

Comment: Why would it be permissible to use when Shabbat comes in? Isnt it already the 9th of Av?

Comment: What @mevaqesh said. Also, I thought that stuff doesn't "become [fully] muktzeh" Shabbos until nightfall